# change menu bar background color

Tags: winapi, menu, menubar

I tried SetMenuInfo with MIM_BACKGROUND, but it doesn't work. I found it is because the Visual Style is enabled. But I don't want to disable the Visual Style by SetWindowTheme(hwndMain, L"", L"") becauuse it will change the appearance of the title bar and border...etc.

Is there any way to change, and only change the background color of the menu bar, without disalbe Visual Style of the main window. By "only change", I also mean that I don't have to draw the menu items myself, like I can use custom draw for change only the background color of toolbar, tab...etc. (But I can find custom draw for menu bar!).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647558%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items

Comment: It seems to me that it is owner-draw of menu items, but "the whole menu bar"

Comment: You have to turn off themes. Because otherwise how will you know that your alternate menu bar background color will look good in the user's selected theme?

Answer (score 2):

You just set MainMenu's `OwnerDraw` Property to true, and Menu is automatically close Menu's theme, but don't close Window's theme!

Comment: How do you do that for an .RC drawn menu?

Answer (score 0):

With themes there is no official way to change the color. However you can take advantage of some undocumented window messages to implement the custom drawing yourself. https://github.com/adzm/win32-custom-menubar-aero-theme